# Re-use rules and avoid CyclicGraphException with snakemake

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I'm writing a pipeline in which a first mapping of reads on a reference genome results in a sam file (rule `map_on_genome`), and then in a sorted and indexed bam file (rule `sam2indexedbam`). After processing this bam file (rule `small_RNA_seq_annotate`), I extract some reads that I would like to re-map again on the same genome with the same parameters. I also trim extra nucleotides from reads that did not map during the first mapping (rule `extract_nomap_siRNAs`), and I would like to try to map the resulting trimmed reads again similarly.

Ideally, the `rules map_on_genome` and `sam2indexedbam` would therefore be used a first time before `small_RNA_seq_annotate` and `extract_nomap_siRNAs` and then again on the output of these rules.

In my attempt to do so, a wildcard I name `read_type` was supposed to help snakemake make the difference between the first mapping and the other, but apparently I failed because I end up getting the following error:

```
Cyclic dependency on rule sam2indexedbam.
```

**What is the recommended way to achieve what I want (i.e. avoid code duplication)?**

---

#### Example

I tried to reproduce the error in a simplified version of my real pipeline. Here is an example that results in `CyclicGraphException`:

```python
rule all:
    input:
        expand("results/{read_type}_on_genome_sorted.bam", read_type=["reads", "nomap_siRNA", "piRNA", "siRNA", "miRNA"]),


def source_fastq(wildcards):
    if wildcards.read_type == "nomap_siRNA":
        return rules.extract_nomap_siRNA.output.fastq
    elif wildcards.read_type == "piRNA":
        return rules.small_RNA_seq_annotate.output.pi_fastq
    elif wildcards.read_type == "siRNA":
        return rules.small_RNA_seq_annotate.output.si_fastq
    elif wildcards.read_type == "miRNA":
        return rules.small_RNA_seq_annotate.output.mi_fastq
    elif wildcards.read_type == "reads":
        return "data/reads.fastq"
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError("Unknown read type: %s" % wildcards.read_type)


rule map_on_genome:
    input:
        source_fastq
    output:
        sam = "results/{read_type}_on_genome.sam",
        nomap = "results/{read_type}_nomap.fastq"
    shell:
        """
        touch {output}
        """

rule extract_nomap_siRNA:
    input:
        rules.map_on_genome.output.sam
        #"results/reads_nomap.fastq"
    output:
        fastq = "results/{read_type}_unmapped_siRNA.fastq"
    shell:
        """
        touch {output}
        """

rule sam2indexedbam:
    input:
        rules.map_on_genome.output.sam
    output:
        "results/{read_type}_on_genome_sorted.bam"
    shell:
        """
        touch {output}
        """

rule small_RNA_seq_annotate:
    input:
        "results/reads_on_genome_sorted.bam"
    output:
        pi_fastq = "results/piRNA.fastq",
        si_fastq = "results/siRNA.fastq",
        mi_fastq = "results/miRNA.fastq"
    shell:
        """
        touch {output.pi_fastq}
        touch {output.si_fastq}
        touch {output.mi_fastq}
        """
```

#### Solution

If I change the input of rule `extract_nomap_siRNA` to a hard-coded file path instead of the output of the `map_on_genome` rule, the error disappears.

I suppose this hard-coding breaks the cyclic dependency.

Comment: Is there anymore relevant code you could post so we could see why you may be getting this error? Do you know what a cyclic dependency is?

Comment: @nbryans I added an example, and while constructing the example I think I found the reason for the cyclic dependency.